# Django install as local app

Tags: python, django

all. I am trying to use the Django-Plupload in my project(src:https://github.com/vellonce/django-plupload). And I need to customize the view.py of this external app. Since I am developing in my localhost and I need to deploy it on server in the future, I don't want it to stay in site package. Instead, I want to install it as local app. May I know what is the suitable way to do this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to modify it, download the source and include it in your project (you will have to check license terms of the package)
Simply paste the app folder inside your project and add it to "installed apps"

Comment: Thank you. In the folder, there's other files like manage.py, setting.py. Will these files bring problem? I have tried but it shows plupload unresolved reference in setting.INSTALLED_APPS. May I know how to resolve it?

Comment: @WeiXu just download the app directory `plupload` and put it in your apps directory, and add it to your INSTALLED_APPS, the settings.py WILL be a problem

Comment: How about the folder django_plupload? May I know where should I put it?